# Pick lines with keyword list in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a query list and a file with lines containing it. I wish to iterate for over it and pick lines matching the keyword in query list. For example,

Querylist.txt:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

ClusterList.txt

```
XX  YY  A   zz
C   B   CC
1   2   3   4   5
this    does    not contain
trial   sample  line
```

I tried the following:

```
with open('QueryList.txt','r') as query:
    entriesInquery = query.readlines()
print(entriesInquery)
out = []
for element in entriesInquery:
    for line in open('ClusterList.txt'):
        if element in line.split('\t'):
            open('newfile.txt','w').writelines(line)
```

The output I got is: `C B CC`

I should be getting:

```
XX YY A zz
C B CC
```

Why is my code picking only element corresponding to `C` and not `A`? Please suggest.

Comment: Each time you `open('newfile.txt','w')` you are truncating the file so you only keep the last write, also I doubt you want writelines to write a single line

Comment: Changing it to 'a' still did not help. I want to writelines to write in successive lines. That is the reason I put it inside loop.

Comment: it definitely did help as you are not overwriting data, *I want to writelines to write in successive lines.*, how is `XX YY A zz` on successive lines? What do you think writelines actually does?

Comment: I found that it is writing strings. I found other method to write the output. Thanks !